# Add an entire domain to Java Exception list

Tags: windows, java

I'm administering hundreds of machines with Java interfaces that I sometimes need to get into.  Unfortunately, the default Java settings in Windows block all of these applications from running, presumably because they use self-signed certificates.  This means every time I want to get into a Java based management console on a machine, I have to manually add that URL to my Java exceptions list (in Windows).

According to the Oracle documentation, wildcards are not supported, but domains are:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/deploy/exception_site_list.html

I'd like to add "https://example.com" into my Exceptions list and just have it allow everything under my domain.  According to the documentation above, it sounds like this should work:

> Wildcards are not supported. If only a domain is provided, any RIA
>   from that domain is  allowed to run. A domain can have multiple
>   entries, for example, https://www.example.com and
>   http://www.example.com.

However, it isn't working for me.  I've added my top level domain for both http and https access, and it does not work.  It only seems to work if the FQDN fully matches, which means I have to add every URL manually.  Am I doing something wrong here?  There has to be a better way to do this, aside from disabling Java security.  I'm running Java 8 on Windows 7.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm in the exact situation. Only FQDN seem to work AND it wants the port number I'm working on. It's ridiculous. Oracle's java tagline should now be "NOW MORE USELESS THAN EVER." Instead of patching their holes in the coding, they lock down things TIGHT in v8 and defeat their own purpose. Sad.